# Type hints in Angular/typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I am using Angular's [Drag and Drop module](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) where I'm passing property `id` as an Array of two ints:

```
<div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" [id]="[x, y]">
```

When I try to access the array, the angular compiler considers it a string:

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    const a = event.container.id.map(x => parseInt(x));
```

gives me the error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Is there a way to hint to the compiler about the type of the underlying data? When I print it with `console.log`, it shows as an Array of ints.

Comment: The `id` property of a `CdkDropList` is a `string`: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/drag-drop/directives/drop-list.ts#L100

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-drag-and-drop-list-dlkcm2 use any as type in function